# html emails - problem with <button> inside <a> tags?

Tags: html, html-email

The following looks fine but when i test it in gmail, it opens the link twice (in 2 new tabs), it's as if there's some kind of wierd event bubbling happening....

```
<a href="some_url"> <button>Approve</button> </a>
```

am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A link can't contain a button. Either use a button or style the link like a button (i.e. that it looks like a button).

That said: The event bubbling is probably happening because the button does it's job and then, the link processes the mouse click event, too.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious thing is that this is not properly formatted [X]HTML.
An `<a>` should not include a `<button>`

Answer (score 2):

There are browsers that will not even allow the link to be clicked.
Style the href instead

```
<a href="" style="text-decoration:none; border-top: 2px #cce3ff solid; border-left: 2px #cce3ff solid; border-bottom: 2px #31557f solid;border-right: 2px #31557f solid;">GO</a>
```